# MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model cant find resolve

Tags: mongodb, model, schema, mongoose-populate

I'm trying to do a populate in mongo I've tried everything but I always get this error. I'm really frustrated already

mi function

```
 const trade = Trade.find({ useradmin: idUser }).populate('type')
```

model trade

```
import mongoose from "mongoose"

export interface iTrade extends mongoose.Document{
    useradmin     : string,
    type          : string,
    status        : boolean
}

const TradeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   
    useradmin:{
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'usuario requerido']
    },
    type:{
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "TradeType"
    },
    status:{
        type: Boolean,
        required:false,
        default: true,
    }
},
{ collection: 'trade', timestamps: true, versionKey: 'version' })

TradeSchema.methods.toJSON = function () {
    const {__v,version, ... data } = this.toObject();
    return data;
}

const Trade = mongoose.model<iTrade>("trade", TradeSchema)
export default Trade
```

model TradeType

```
import mongoose from "mongoose"

export interface iTradeType extends mongoose.Document{
    name     : string
}

const TradeTypeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   
    name: {
        type: String
    }
},
{ collection: 'tradeType', timestamps: true, versionKey: 'version' })

TradeTypeSchema.methods.toJSON = function () {
    const {__v,version, ... data } = this.toObject();
    return data;
}

const TradeType = mongoose.model<iTradeType>("TradeType", TradeTypeSchema)
export default TradeType
```

It doesn't matter if I change the name of the model, always the same error, I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I've been doing this for hours, it really has me frustrated. Has anyone happened to it?

Answer (score 0):

Once try with the actual collection name you have mentioned in collection

```
const TradeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   
    useradmin:{
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'usuario requerido']
    },
    type:{
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "tradeType" // CHANGE THE ref NAME
    },
    status:{
        type: Boolean,
        required:false,
        default: true,
    }
},
{ collection: 'trade', timestamps: true, versionKey: 'version' })
```

Try with the actual name, and one thing, did you get the trade object without the trade type on the above query?

Comment: Hello dear, this code:  ` const trade = Trade.find({ useradmin: idUser }).populate({path:"type", model: TradeType, select:'name'})`.  I saw it in another forum and it was the only thing that worked for me, I had never seen a populate like this, not even in the mongoose documentation, I don't really know where it came from, but that's the only way it worked